# Is there significant performance difference between break and return in a loop at the end of a C function?

Tags: c++, c, assembly

Consider the following (Obj-)C(++) code segment as an example:

```
// don't blame me for the 2-space indents. It's insane to type 12 spaces.
int whatever(int *foo) {
  for (int k = 0; k < bar; k++) { // I know it's a boring loop
    do_something(k);
      if (that(k))
        break; // or return
    do_more(k);
  }
}
```

A friend told me that using `break` is not only more logical (and using `return` causes troubles when someone wants to add something to the function afterwards), but also yields faster code. It's said that the processor gives better predictions in this case for `jmp`-ly instructions than for `ret`.

Or course I agree with him on the first point, but if there is actually some significant difference, why doesn't the compiler optimize it?

Comment: It will never, ever, ever matter if that one instruction to leave the loop is slightly faster.  The code to actually exit the loop does not count as "inner loop" for performance considerations.  It is only executed once.

Comment: Look at the disassembly, for debug and release modes if you want, and then you will know for sure.

Comment: I like that you found it "insane" to type extra spaces, but felt fine typing a justification

Comment: Tip: Format your code in a text editor.  Ensure the outermost level has 4 leading spaces.  Paste it in.

Comment: That is an attempt for premature optimization. With the function call to the `if` condition already and a loop surrounding all that, a difference would not only be hardly noticeable, it wouldn't even be measurable. Do whatever makes your code more readable.

Answer (score 1):

If it's insane to type 2 spaces, use a decent text editor with auto-indent.  4 space indentation is **much** more readable than 2 spaces.

Readability should be a cardinal value when you write C code.

Using `break` or `return` should be chosen based on context to make your code easier to follow and understand.  If not to others, you will be doing a favor to yourself, when a few years from now you will be reading your own code, hunting for a spurious bug and trying to make sense of it.

No matter which option you choose, the compiler will optimize your code its own way and different compilers, versions or configurations will do it differently. No noticeable difference should arise from this choice, and even in the unlikely chance that it would, not a lasting one.

Focus on the choice of algorithm, data structures, memory allocation strategies, possibly memory layout cache implications... These are far more important for speed and overall efficiency than local micro-optimizations.

Answer (score 0):

Any compiler is capable of optimizing jumps to jumps.  In practice, though, there will probably be some cleanup to do before exiting anyway.  When in doubt, profile.  I don’t see how this could make any significant difference.

Stylistically, and especially in C where the compiler does not clean stuff up for me when it goes out of scope, I prefer to have a single point of return, although I don’t go so far as to `goto` one.